# Android espresso test

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I have just started using espresso and want to write tests for my android application.
However I have encountered a wall that I dont know how to skip.
I have an imageView that sometimes is not visible sometimes it is visible, and I want to test that part, I know that I can check whether element is visible or not but
inside my fragment class I have method that takes int as parameter, that int comes from database, whether the int is higher than 10, the imageView is visible and my question is: how could I write test for something like that? Do I have to use some kind of mock for my class then call that method and then check whether my imageView is visible or?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe you are having timing problems. Can you post some code of how your data is loaded from the database to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Where is that int retrieved and passed. If the int parameter comes from the previous activity, then you can control the value of the parameter. You can do something like this,

```
Intent = new Intent(..);
   intent.putExtra(parameterName/Id, parameterValue);
   setActivityIntent();
   getActivity();
```

By this way, the value of the parameter will be passed to the activity.